# Android Studio preview window not rendering anything if any appcompat or support v4 widget present

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

I'm using Android Studio 1.2.1.1, Gradle plugin version 1.2.3, Android sdk tools 24.3.1, Platform tools 22, Build tools 22.0.1

Now the problem is that everything is fucked up, I don't remember what my old configuration was but in the xml preview window everything used to render properly.

With this new configuration the preview window does not render any of the support v4 widgets like drawer layout, swipe refresh layout etc. And it would have been okay if it'd just leave those and render the rest but not even the device shows up.

[image]

Also, Android Studio is able to import app-compat library and support library even though I've commented out the dependencies in the gradle.build file (yes, I synced and rebuilt after commenting).

[image]

[image]

without preview it's getting really difficult to do anything.

Comment: Change theme setting in the layout preview with anything from `Theme.AppCompat` parent theme or set Android version to v21

Comment: did you ever solve this? I'm getting the same issue on a newly created project and the suggestions from @ecle don't do anything.

Comment: @AndyBrown yup. There was a bug in the sdk tools. Try installing the latest ones. Should work